# offset.top is giving error when getting for last row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get offset of last row with the class `stops` using below code:

```
var stop =  $('.stops:last').offset.top();
```

but i am getting error: object doesnot support property `"top"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is no method `.top()`, use:

```
var stop =  $('.stops:last').offset().top;
```

instead.

It's about jQuery, i don't know what framework are you use. If another - tell us.

Comment: i did that but in alert i am getting undefined for that

Comment: Unable to get value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined

Comment: Do you really have this objects: $('.stops:last') ? I'll try to create jsfiddle for you.

Comment: oh seems like i made a mistake in class name.. working now. thanks :)